# Why was this Comment Flag Declined?

Tags: discussion, comments, flagging

I'm not really a regular on this part of Stack Exchange, but I assume comments are treated roughly the same on all Stack Exchange sites.

Recently I saw a [comment](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/12506/what-are-the-drawbacks-of-the-us-making-tactical-first-use-of-nuclear-weapons-ag#comment42986_12506) on a question which didn't seem to be asking for clarification at all, just making tangential commentary. As always (well, when I think of it), I flag such comments as "not constructive".

However this particular flag was declined, which surprised me as I had previously flagged a likewise non-constructive comment on the same question which was removed.

Was I mistaken? Did I use the wrong flag? Did I flag the previous comment correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After thinking it for a while, I came to the conclusion that comment thread had what looked like the beginning of a side conversation about small-payload nukes, and the usefulness of nukes, so I went and migrated that to chat.

Answer (score 2):

I did not delete this comment because even though I do not consider it *very* relevant, I still don't considered it irrelevant enough to delete it. I deleted the first comment which went into a similar direction, because it was far more opinionated and "campaigny" than the one I left alone:

> You may be overthinking this. Trump has generally opposed any promise on not using military force. That's actually the correct stance to take, as we can't establish now what the parameters of a future issue might be. It's Hillary Clinton's willingness to promise not to use ground troops that should be scary--without a ground troops option, a less discriminate bombing operation is more likely. Clinton also has a proven willingness to interfere in other countries without thinking through the consequences: Iraq; Egypt; Libya; Syria.

However, a second flag was raised on the comment. I intentionally decided not to handle this flag to get a second opinion from another mod.

Comment: I'm kind of on the fence on this one.  On one hand, the comment is tangential to the question, but on the other hand, it's not ruining the whole comment section, and the comment section isn't quite crazy enough yet to require pruning.