# Why was my comment flag declined?

Tags: discussion, support, comments, flagging, declined-flags

I recently flagged [this comment](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/69507/why-is-regenerons-monoclonal-antibody-covid-19-treatment-not-being-used-in-cana#comment281719_69507):

> It is clearly a political question because it asks about an action of the government of Canada. **I do not know an answer,** though (**same as @JoeC**).

(Emphasis mine)

#### My reasoning for flagging the comment:

It says that Joe C does not know the answer. Unless there is some deleted comment to the question that I cannot see, Joe C never said that they don’t know the answer. This means the comment is essentially saying that Joe C doesn’t know stuff. In my opinion, this is unfriendly and unkind. For example, if I said “You don’t know how to count” it would be unfriendly and unkind. This is essentially what the comment is saying, in my opinion.

#### Question

Why was this flag declined?

<sub>Note: for anybody who thinks this is off topic, please look at [1](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4057/why-was-this-naa-flag-declined), [2](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4647/why-was-this-flag-declined), [3](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3195/why-is-this-post-not-rude-or-abusive-as-evidenced-by-declined-flag), [4](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2750/why-was-this-comment-flag-declined), [5](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3385/why-was-this-flag-declined), [6](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3717/declined-flag-on-an-egregiously-sexist-and-passive-aggressive-answer), none of which are closed</sub>

Comment: What exactly is wrong with saying someone else doesn't know an answer?

Comment: @JoeW if I replied to all of your comments saying “Joe W doesn’t know the answer” that would be mean, because I would basically be calling you can idiot.

Comment: First off there is a big difference between replying to all my comments and a single one, if there is evidence that they are making a similar reply to all comments that should be a moderator flag and asked as a public question. Second to answer your question that wouldn't bother me at all.

Comment: @JoeW I agree that there is a difference between replying to all comments and just one. However, IMO the difference is simply an issue of scale, not whether or not it is unfriendly. Also, I guess you just have a [thicker skin](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/thick%20skin) than me :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I declined the flag because I didn't connect with your reasoning. When you flagged it, all I saw was the comment itself and the *unfriendly or unkind* flag (without your reasoning).

Looking at it again with the context in this meta question, I see your point but I'm not sure if the commenter intended it to be read that way.

That said, I don't really see what the *(same as @JoeC)* part of the comment is supposed to convey. Since that part doesn't add anything while the rest of the comment argues against Joe C's point that the question is off-topic, I will remove the part in brackets (because it's needlessly confusing) but leave the rest of the comment.